Image upload by rest api to TikTok integration via image string generated by binary
I am trying to make http multipart request from my app to tiktok, but getting the response
**param body.data is invalid,detail:type incorrect,expected type:binary**

here is the my code:
    public function uploadToTikTok(
    string $endpoint,
    TikTokStoreAuthData $authData,
    array $query = [],
    $body = null,
    string $requestOptionType = RequestOptions::MULTIPART,
): array {
    $options = [
        $requestOptionType => [
            [
                'contents' => file_get_contents(body['image_url']),
                'name' => 'data',
            ],
        ]
    ];
    $url = $this->buildUrl($endpoint, $authData, $query);

    return (array)$this->client->post($url, $options);
}

here is the documentation from tiktok
as TikTok ducumenation, they are requiring to send image as a string from binary
could you please suggest if i am doing something wrong? how should i format my contents value to get the successful response from tiktok?
Any help will be highly appreciated!

What is body['image_url'] supposed to be? You actually got a constant named body, that is an array ...?

Supply the 'filename' directive against the data parameter, even though this is supposed to be optional.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#filename
